# NSFetchedResultsController can't performFetch when sorted attributes aren't all the same

Tags: core-data, ios5, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a strange issue with an `NSFetchedResultsController` that can only handle `performFetch` when all the `entity.number`s are the same number (this `NSFetchedResultsController` sorts the entities using `number`. This is kind of like a playlist that uses an `indexNumber` attribute to keep the playlist order.

```
- (IBAction)addSetPressed {
    int theNumber = [self.nameTextField.text intValue];
    WSet *set = [WSet wSetWithNumber:theNumber inManagedObjectContext:self.workout.managedObjectContext];
    [self.workout addExercisesObject:set];
}
```

`self.nameTextField` is in my `UITableView`'s Header. I'll put a number there, like `1` for example, and then I press a `UIButton` that calls `addSetPressed`. This code is meant to add an entity to my model and the `NSFetchedResultsController` detects the change in the model and updates my `UITableView`.

Here's the issue:
When I enter `1` (or any number) in `self.nameTextField`, I can press the `UIButton` as many times as I want to and the code works great. But when I change the number in `self.nameTextField` I get an error:

```
[__NSCFNumber localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb665b80
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.
```

I have spent the last 12 hours messing around with my code and researching the issue, but I can't figure it out.

It will be great if you a and tip for me, or can point me towards some literature that can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed!

Here's the problem. When I setup my `sortDescriptor`, I need to select the appropriate selector to compare the type of attribute I'm sorting by.

This is correct since number is handled as an `NSNumber`

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)]];
```

I had the selector for `NSString` before.

Comment: Huge thanks. I was looking at the completely wrong place, thinking that the controller that changed the date was the problem, when the one causing the application to crash was the tableViewController that had segued into it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `NSNumber` doesn't like being sent the method `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`.

I'm going to play around with this to see if I can make the sort value an `NSString` instead.

If you have any better ideas, let me know!