# Application crashes using core data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, crash, nsnumber

I am using core data for saving data. First time my application saves data without any issue but 2nd time application crashes on `[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];` line with crash log

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x98dda90'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e6e012 0x179ee7e 0x1ef94bd 0x1e5dbbc 0x1e5d94e 0xeeae92 0xf645ee 0x15ca8f5 0x15c5785 0x15c8061 0xf53dc9 0x1ec80c5 0x1e22efa 0xe88482 0x14da5f3 0x1573e5f 0x14d5a26 0x14d916e 0x77ca 0x7d4e 0x17b2705 0x3dd920 0x619b24 0x17b2705 0x3dd920 0x3dd8b8 0x49e671 0x49ebcf 0x49dd38 0x40d33f 0x40d552 0x3eb3aa 0x3dccf8 0x1dc9df9 0x1dc9ad0 0x1de3bf5 0x1de3962 0x1e14bb6 0x1e13f44 0x1e13e1b 0x1dc87e3 0x1dc8668 0x3da65c 0x3efd 0x2425)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I am using following code for saving data

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    Projects *projects = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Projects" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"object id %@", projects.objectID);
    projects.title = projectTitleTxtFld.text;
    projects.descProject = descriptionTxtView.text;
    projects.type = projectType.text;
    projects.recID = [self generateRandom];
    NSLog(@"rec id %@", projects.recID);
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil]; //here my app crashes
    NSLog(@"title %@", projects.title);
 }

-(NSNumber*)generateRandom
{
    int number = arc4random();
    if (number < 0) {
        number = number * -1;
    }
    NSNumber *newNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:number];
    return newNumber;
}
```

Comment: does projects.recID in data model is same type as `-[self generateRandom]` ?

Comment: The exception sounds me like you have set a NSNumber to a NSString property and trying to sort/compare...

Comment: @RolandasR projects.recID is of NSNumber type

Comment: @Mert projects.recID is of NSNumber type and i am trying to assign it an NSNumber. I have edited the code you may check my "GenrateRandom" Method

Comment: The GenerateRandom method looks ok. I'm suspicious with project type. But can you please add your properties to your question, before I try to guess which property type is wrong. Please check also the data types in your coredata model.

Comment: NSString * descProject;
NSNumber * recID;
NSString * title;
NSString * type;

Comment: What is the logs from the run. (First save and the second one when it doesn't work)

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970968/nsfetchedresultscontroller-cant-performfetch-when-sorted-attributes-arent-all

Comment: Could you please use the following code? `NSError* error = nil; if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {// log the error here...}`

Comment: @flexaddicted I tried this now but when it was checkin this condition at that time my app crashed with this log *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x98a9340'

Answer (score 0):

Its actually because of wrong data type you are trying to insert into the coredata.
From the error log what i feel is that there is some number that is assigned to the a coredata attribute which is a string.
Please have check for all the data that you are inserting using

```
NSLog(@"class %@",[object class]);
```

and check whether the core data field data type and the object data type that you are inserting are both the same

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've just had this issue. I set a question to 0 % compliant on a left swipe and 100% on a right swipe. In core data i have an NSNumber data type for the attribute  compliantPercentage.

i wrap a simple int number into the NSNumber using [NSNumber numberWithInt:100]

my view is a table view controller with core data hence the fetched results controller. the code snippet is:

```
CheckSectionQuestion *theQuestion;
theQuestion = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
theQuestion.compliantPercentage=[NSNumber numberWithInt:100];
theQuestion.completed=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

now, while this updates the table view and looks like it has updated core data, something hasn't worked. if i go back to the previous view controller using the navigation controller, then back into this view controller for ANY question - not JUST the one i have just updated i get the error you mention.

the solution?

very simple - explicitly save the changes.

ie

```
CheckSectionQuestion *theQuestion;
theQuestion = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

theQuestion.compliantPercentage=[NSNumber numberWithInt:100];
theQuestion.completed=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

//***** make sure CD saves the changes
NSError * error;
if ([theQuestion.managedObjectContext  save:&error]) {
      NSLog(@"saved");
}
```

hope that this helps

Comment: just to note - I HAD already checked the data types, etc they were all correct, explicitly saving the data was the only change i made tot he code to stop it crashing